# Minecraft launcher (1.3.7 for 1.7.4) is not working!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

This is why it is not working:

links are either broken or not working properly because of a glitch,etc.

it says "welcome, ********! ready to play minecraft 1.7.4." but when I click on the button
"play" it does not launch the game like the past times I played minecraft.

the scroll is not working when I clicked it.

Please help!

Comment: What does the launcher say under "Development Console" tab?

Comment: I cannot click the "Development Console" tab. It is either bugged,glitched, or broken. (I am replying to 3ventic)

Comment: "Minecraft fails to launch" without a crash report is not specific enough to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not clear what you've already done and under what environment you're running the Minecraft launcher on, the best I can do is give you a few suggestions:

1. Download the Minecraft launcher again from [the official website](https://minecraft.net/download). Did you try both the .exe and the .jar?
2. [Install](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) the newest version of Java. Maybe you still have Java 6.
3. Wait. On 31 Dec 2013, there was a possible DDoS by DerpTrolling ([see here](https://twitter.com/DerpTrolling/status/418232499148296193)), so services could still be running slow.

If you're on a school network, chances are that Minecraft is blocked, and you tried downloading the launcher from another website. In that case, you're on your own.

Comment: maybe it is the DDoS